# Blender / Unity - Which one do I paint on? low poly or high poly

Tags: unity, blender

I created two versions of my object. One high poly and one low poly. I sculpted the high poly one and plan on baking a normal map so that my low poly one can have more detail.

My question is, once all the sculpting is done and I get everything ready to create a normal map. Which object do I begin painting on the high poly (sculpted) or low poly(non sculpted)?

Comment: I don't have much experience on sculpting, but isn't the idea that you do everything on the high poly and then apply the changes to the low poly ones?

Comment: Have you experienced any problems doing this the way that makes the most sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

May I answer you now. Normal Game Art workflow: Map shall be paint on high poly in Blender, bake high-poly details (Texture maps, normal maps, etc.) to Low-poly.  Or Map can be painted on 3rd party software(Photoshop, etc) after maps and low-poly exported. Thank you.

Tutorials:

1. Gamedev Fred (2018). Blender Bake to Lowpoly. [https://youtu.be/o568T79egTs][1](https://youtu.be/o568T79egTs): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o568T79egTs